# MongoDB collection design joining data

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, nosql

I have an application where the client wants to see multiple types of documents in the same list: (Purchase Orders, Payments, Travel requests). They want to be able to do text search on certain fields that exist in all three document types and be able to sort it on certain fields also that all three documents have. The list also has to be paged.

I originally had planned on having the documents in separate collections because they are obviously different types of documents but i'm not sure how to accomplish this full list they want since i would have to combine the collections together to form 1 list efficiently.

I really want to avoid making one collection that contains all these different document types since I don't think its a good way to organize data nor do I think this list view should be the deciding factor on how we organize the data but i'm not sure if there would be a speed factor in separating them into the 3 collections, filtering and joining the data, then performing the sort and paging on the joined list.  Anyone have any suggestions on what I should do or if anyone had experience in a similar situation?

Comment: mongoDB is quite fast on its own, so joining few hundreds list, won't bother much.

Comment: sorry, not sure what you are referring to. You mean using one collection or splitting the collections and joining them in code?  If its joining them in code, the separate collections could have thousands of records in each that have to put into 1 list and then sorted. Can node handle that kind of processing or is there a way to do this on the database itself?

Comment: Mongo has some great inbuilt features, like `aggregation` framework and all. And IMO you should store data in separate collections and join them later on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make diffrent collections for each Purchase Orders, Payments, Travel requests.

Mongodb provides a feature of **aggregation**. Aggregation operations group values from multiple documents together, and can perform a variety of operations on the grouped data to return a single result. So it helps you to search fields in all other documents.

You can learn aggregation here [Mongodb aggregation](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mongodb/mongodb_aggregation.htm)